# @JsonIgnor not working on UserDetails class Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to make a blog using spring boot java with auth.

I created `User` class the implements `UserDetails`, and Post class.

When using the path `/posts` I wish to see all the posts in the blog, problem is that each post contains `creator` (User obj) and it shows the password of the user - and this is what I'm trying to avoid.

I tried `@JsonIgnor`, `@JsonProperty` didn't work
Tried also `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` I get an error on the  `Access.WRITE_ONLY`.

Does are the classes:

```
package com.example.blog.entities;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, List<Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    @JsonProperty
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String title;
    private String body;
    private LocalDate date;

    @ManyToOne
    private User creator;

    public Post() {
    }
}
```

```
import com.example.blog.entities.Post;
import com.example.blog.entities.User;
import com.example.blog.repositories.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PostService(PostRepository postRepository){
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }

    public List<Post> getAllPosts(){
        return postRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void insert(Post post) {
        if(post.getBody() == null || post.getTitle() == null ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing args");
        }
        post.setDate(LocalDate.now());
        postRepository.save(post);
    }

    public List<Post> getPostByUsername(User user){
        return postRepository.findByCreatorId(user.getId());
    }
}
```

The endpoint:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/posts")
    public List<Post> posts(){
        return postService.getAllPosts();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not expose your internal data model (JPA). Use transport classes. And you should remove the "@JsonProperty" from "public void setPassword(String password) ...". It is contradicting ("overriding") the "@JsonIgnore". And don't store your password as plaintext! Use for example jBCrypt.
My Setup:

```
    public static class XUser {
    private String username;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    //@JsonProperty
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}

@Test
public void testJson() {
    XUser user = new XUser();
    user.setPassword("oh shit!");
    user.setUsername("name");
    try {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(user));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
{"username":"name"}
```

Comment: I removed the `@JsonProperty` still not ignoring the password

Comment: Added my example and the output.

Comment: Just saw your import statement: import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore; It should be import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;.